# Assign a variable and check existence of hash key

Tags: perl

With the little that I know about Perl, I was surprised that this syntax doesn't work:

```
if (exists $wid = $dict{$w}) {
 print "$wid:$c\n";
}
```

It seems I can't make the assignment `$wid = $dict{$w}` and check if it exists at the same time:

> exists argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or a subroutine at
>   createWordIndex.pl line 31.

Is there a way to do this kind of assignment? Or do I just need to check existence first and then make the assignment if the condition is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to figure out if there's a value there before you print it?  Then you'll have to do it this way:

```
if ( exists($dict{$w}) ) {
    my $wid = $dict{$w};
    print "$wid: $c\n";
}
```

If you know that the values stored will always be defined, you can do

```
if ( defined( my $wid = $dict{$w} ) ) {
    print "$wid: $c\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (TIMTOWTDI, after all), you can use the smart match operator (for Perl version >= 5.10):

```
if($w ~~ (keys %dict))
{
  my $wid = $dict{$w};
  print "$wid: $c\n";
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
if(grep{$w eq $_}(keys %dict))
{
  my $wid = $dict{$w};
  print "$wid: $c\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just answered your question in your question.

> "Or do I just need to check existence first and then make the assignment if the condition is true?"

the **exists** function in your code takes in the scalar $wid. And is clearly stated in your error that the exists function needs a hash or array element

> exists argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or a subroutine at createWordIndex.pl line 31.

so yes. you need to check first if it exists.

friendly advice: try all the things/solutions that you can think of before asking because you might already know the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it, just skip the `exists`.  if the assignment is made (because there is a $dict{$w}) the side-effect is true.

```
my %dict;

$dict{one} = 1;
$dict{two} = 2;
$dict{three} = 3;

if ($wid = $dict{four}) {
  print "$wid\n";
}
else {
  print "NO!\n";
}
```

Comment: There is a problem if `$dict{four}` exists but its value is `0`