# Correct use of Perl "exists"

Tags: perl, hash

I have two files. The first two columns in both are chromosome loci and genotypes, for instance `chr1:1736464585` and `T/G`.

I have put the first two columns into a hash. I want to check whether the hash key (the chromosome locus) exists in the second file.

I have written this Perl program and have tried many variations but I'm not sure if I'm using `exists` correctly: it gives the error `exists is not an HASH or ARRAY element or a subroutine`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $output = "annotated.txt";
open( O, ">>$output" );

my $filename  = "datatest.txt";
my $filename2 = "MP2.txt";

chomp $filename;
chomp $filename2;

my %hash1 = ();

open( FN1, $filename ) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
my @lines = <FN1>;

foreach my $line (@lines) {

    my @split = split /\t/, $line;

    if ( $line =~ /^chr/ ) {

        my ( $key, $value ) = ( $split[0], $split[1] );
        $hash1{$key} = $value;
    }
}

my $DATA;
open( $DATA, $filename2 ) or die $!;
my @lines2 = <$DATA>;

foreach my $line2 (@lines2) {

    my @split2 = split /\t/, $line2;

    if ( $line2 =~ /^chr/ ) {

        if ( exists %hash1{$key} ) {

            print "$line2\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804351/assign-a-variable-and-check-existence-of-hash-key ?

Comment: White space — indentation and blank lines — is free of charge and will make your software much more convenient for you to visualise and debug. If you have to ask others to help you then it is only polite to make your code as readable as possible. In this instance I have done it for you.

Comment: You must specify exists on a scalar $hash{key}

Comment: Thanks Borodin, apologies - this is the first time I have posted so was unsure of this etiquette.

Answer (score 9):

The syntax of the following line is incorrect:

```
if (exists %hash1{$key}) { ... }
```

This should be:

```
if (exists $hash1{$key}) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Bjerre and Abhay!